# Is it possible to exploit the exhaust air of a vacuum cleaner ? (Air blower, generator,…)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, applied-physics

I am working on new design ideas for vacuum cleaner and I need help to understand fluid mechanics aspects. I have ideas about the exploitation of the air exhausted by the fan.

First, I wonder if we could obtain a strong blowing flow if we have a narrow tube a the exit instead of the standard aerations. In that way, the suction entry would be used as a standard vacuum cleaner and the blowing exit would be used as an air blower.

The other idea would be to put a wind turbine behind the suction fan in order to recharge the battery of the latter. Considering the energy losses of course, how much could it increase the battery life? I obtained a, probably far optimistic, result that correspond to double the battery life.

In either case, I wonder if my ideas are physically coherent. Generally, is it ok to modify the exit of a vacuum cleaner without compromising the power of suction? Especially in the second case, I suspect that it might be a naive idea and I wonder if such a perturbation of the air flow would make the fundamental mechanism of the fan impossible.

Comment: My leaf blower will also vacuum/mulch leaves. Generally changing the design of the exhaust will change the characteristics.

Comment: Sounds like you want to re-invent the [*wet-dry vacuum*](https://www.google.com/search?q=wet+dry+vacuum) (also often called simply "shop vac"), which does the suction+exhaust aspect already (in fact, mine has a foam pad to insert into the exhaust port to increase suction!).

Answer (score 0):

Basically no. If we assign the downstream direction to be positive, doing positive mechanical work on a column of air increases the downstream pressure (blows downstream) and decreases the upstream pressure (sucks upstream), which is how a vacuum cleaner makes suction. Doing negative work on the column of air (that is: you get the air do do work on a generator or debris you want to blow away) does the opposite, decreasing the downstream pressure and increasing the upstream pressure.

A vacuum cleaner that makes the column of air do work on something else is a vacuum cleaner with a higher upstream pressure, that is, less suction.

As regards a blower, blowers are tremendously inefficient - most of the wind keeps going, while only a small amount of work is done on debris near the outlet. Precisely *because* of this inefficiency, having a vacuum cleaner that blows from one direction while it sucks from the other direction is feasible: if only a tiny fraction of the kinetic energy of the air from a blower is converted into downstream work, only a tiny fraction of upstream suction is lost.

In fact there are already machines that do this - some workshop vacuum cleaners have an option to engage a blower. (A web search for "shopvac with blower" will give many examples.) And then of course there are machines whose only purpose is to suck anything and everything in one side, chop it up if necessary, and blow it out the other side - jet engines, lawnmowers, mulchers, etc.